# How to write a recursion triggers using on Custom Object?

Tags: trigger

I am Creating one custom object and create one new field that is 'Count' which is Number data type. When creating a record , I give '1' in count field and save it. My requirement is when i edit and save that record in that situation it will be automatically change to '2' and '3','4' like this process again and again using recursion trigger. Please Give me any related example using on custom object.

Comment: What do you mean by recursion?? If you want to increase value every time record save you can simply increment the value of field and save it.

Comment: @Mr.Frodo, Yes, that's correct. Recursion is a process in which a function calls itself as a subroutine. This allows the function to be repeated several times, since it calls itself during its execution.  Please give me any examples

Comment: every time it is edited by a user? or every time it undergoes the save process?

Comment: @cropredy,  Every time edited by the user.

Comment: if 'every time edited by user' - then you're going to need a VF controller as trigger is going to get invoked for non-user events (like data loader). Because your question is on hold - you'll need to follow the directions as indicated

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, what you're looking for isn't recursion. My understanding of your question is that you want to increment a field every time a record is edited.

A simple workflow rule and field update can accomplish what you're trying to do. Something like...

- Evaluation Criteria: Created and every time the record is edited
- Rule Criteria: I prefer formulas over the picklists. Either `true` or `ISCHANGED(LastModifiedDate)` should work

The field update formula should be trivial. It's a good idea to check for a null value, but that's about the only complication.